# Refactor method that uses input parameters as return types

Tags: java, refactoring

I have a similar block of code which takes in 3 parameters and uses two of them for returning values, like so:

```
int getAttempts(int foo, List<Object> bar, List<Object> baz) {

      int count = 5;
      bar.add(new Object()); // These both require further method calls before they are populated.
      baz.add(new Object());

      return count;

}
```

The above is a simplistic example but it covers what is the problem.

**Having the input parameters modified makes it difficult to reason about the behaviour.**

So any ideas for a clean refactor ?

One option is making a wrapper object but I don't think that is a feasible option since for every other method I have to make separate wrapper objects.

Comment: One of the things about refactoring code is the strategy quite often depends on the specifics of the code. The code you've shown seems too simplified to give an answer.

Comment: In particular: "uses input parameters as return types" it's not clear what you mean by this: the return type is `int`. Are you saying this is related to... `foo`?

Comment: @AndyTurner I meant it uses the arguments passed to it as containers for outputting values.

Comment: That's got nothing to do with its return type then.

Comment: @AndyTurner, [Output parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)#Output_parameters) are often referred to as _return parameters_. In this case the OP has named them return types instead. They are commonly considered "bad practice" in OOP with respect to readability. For example see the book Clean Code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Triplet<Integer, Object, Object> from library org.javatuples.javatuples

https://www.baeldung.com/java-tuples

Comment: This is nice but involves adding of an extra dependency. Anything that can be done natively in Java ?